# Very slow snowsql (cli client) startup

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm facing a performance problem with `snowsql` cli client.
It's very slow to initialize.

Printing the version takes over **6 seconds**

```
$ time snowsql --version                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Version: 1.2.28
snowsql --version  
0.71s user 0.25s system 14% cpu 6.425 tot
```

Any ideas what might be happening there.
Didn't touch the `~/snowsql/.config`.

MacOS 13.5.2 , M1 Max 64GB

Comment: seems to be related to local system. Your command is just to check snoqsql tool version which has nothing to do with the snowflake instance. Disconnect from wireless and try again/close all programs

Answer (score 1):

I contacted the support and apparently it's a known issue under MacOS that

> Yes, on Mac the SnowSQLstartup takes time as compared to Linux
> machines, and below is the reason for the same.
>
> On Linux for example the extract of an upgrade/install to
> $HOME/.snowsql/ is done once and then all subsequent startup
> discover and use it. On macOS, this extraction is performed, but the
> runtime does not appear to use it exclusively as Linux does — it
> extracts over and over every time into ephemeral tmp directories at
> every invocation.